# Multiple arguments in Switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I came across a problem when trying to implement a switch statement. Basically, I am trying to have multiple variables go through the same switch statement in order to prevent myself from repeating unnecessary code.

I have the variables `$mon1`, `$tue1`, `$wed1`, `$thu1`, `$fri1` and I'd like to get all five of those variables individually through the switch statement below. I could simply add a new switch statement for each individual variable but it just seems like there would be a better way to handle this.

EDIT: I added a for each loop and this works rather well. I still have an issue, that being the assignment of variables. If - for example - $mon1 goes through case "3" then the value of $mon1 should be 13 at the end of the switch statement. Currently it does not assign that value. Any pointers?

```
$stress = array($mon1,$tue1,$wed1,$thu1,$fri1);
foreach($stress as $value){
switch ($value) {
    case "1":
        echo "This is 10"; 
        $value = 10;
        break;
    case "2":
        echo "This is 12";
        $value = 12;
        break;
    case "3":
        echo "This is 15";
        $value = 15;
        break;
     case "4":
        echo "This is 17";
        $value = 17;
        break;
     case "5":
        echo "This is 19";
        $value = 19;
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: instead of individual variables, you can take an array, then have an outer loop which would contain this `switch` statement.

Comment: There is none. You have multiple variables and all needs to be handled individually. Example: you cannot say "This is 10" since it won't be "This" anymore - it is just an example to explain why you need individual switches.  On the other hand, I would put my variables in an array instead and loop through in the array to not repeat the code. Or better one, create a simple function receives the variable and return the result then call it for each variable. individually.

Comment: You could store the values in an array indexed by $days that returns the integer that corresponds to that day? i.e. `$dayCode = array(null, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15 );` ? One based array? i.e.`$dcode = $dayCode[$mon1];` ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so that we can verify correct answers for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function for this purpose:

```
function DecideStressByDay($value)
{
  switch ($value) {
    case "1":
        $value = 10;
        break;
    case "2":
        $value = 12;
        break;
    case "3":
        $value = 15;
        break;
     case "4":
        $value = 17;
        break;
     case "5":
        $value = 19;
        break;
  }
  return $value;
}

$mon1 = DecideStressByDay($mon1);
$tue1 = DecideStressByDay($tue1);

...
```

Comment: @Argentum please can check the answer? So the question appear as closed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about code like this:

```
$stresses = array(
    $mon1 => array(10, 12, 13, 17, 19),
    $tue1 => array(10, 12, 15, 17, 19),
    $wed1 => array(10, 12, 15, 17, 19),
    $thu1 => array(10, 12, 15, 17, 19),
    $fri1 => array(10, 12, 15, 17, 19)
); 
/* change constants as per your situation */

foreach($stresses as $day => $stress ){
    $switch ($day) {
        case "1":               
            $value = $stress[0];
            break;
        case "2":
            $value = $stress[1];
            break;
        case "3":
            $value = $stress[2];
            break;
         case "4":
            $value = $stress[3];
            break;
         case "5":
            $value = $stress[4];
            break;
    }  
    /* do something with $value here or it'll get overwritten with every loop*/ 
}
```